# Find the number of ordered pairs of integers $(x, y)$ such that $2167$ divides $3x^2 + 27y^2 + 2021$ with $0 \leq x, y \leq 2166$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the number of ordered pairs of integers $(x, y)$ such that $$2167\ | \ 3x^2 + 27y^2 + 2021$$  with $$0 \leq x, y \leq 2166.$$

In my attempt I tried to restate everything by introducing mod $2167$ but it seems it just simplifies to $x^2+9y^2 \equiv 771 \ (\text{mod}\ 2167)$ but this doesn't really do much. I tried to introduce $2167k+771$ and then again put modulo $3$ to get $x^2 \equiv k \ (\text{mod}\ 3)$ and then just claimed $k=0$ or $1$ and tried to solve per $k$ introduction but it didn't really give me clarity on the complete solution set and also on how to generalise these kind of questions.

Comment: Remember $2167=11\times 197$.

Comment: Is there any property regarding the fact? I tried modulo both and it gives $x^2+9y^2 \equiv 1 \ (mod 11)$. Should it now just be checking possible modulo 11 and then trying respective x,y and then find a system. I thought of CRT but it will lead me to the same place as in the question.

Comment: @user10354138 I just checked all possible modulo and it seems $x,y \equiv \ (\pm1,0) \ (\pm5,\pm1) \ (mod 11)$ gives the correct residue as required. Is this the correct way?

Comment: I would add that only half of non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ are perfect squares for $p >2$ prime

Comment: I checked quickly with CAS, there are $2352$ solutions which is huge !, for which all $0..11$ remainders are taken for $x,y$ and a whole lot of remainders for $197$ are possible. I'm quite puzzled this could be handled easily using this method...

Comment: @zwim Can you kindly post a complete solution ? The approach would really help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $3x^2+27y^2+2021\equiv 3[x^2+(3y)^2-771]\pmod{2167}$.

Let me just state the big theorem:

**Theorem**: The number of solutions $(X,Y)\in\mathbb{F}_p^2$ ($p$ odd prime) to $aX^2+bY^2=f$, where $a,b,f\in\mathbb{F}_p$ with $ab\neq 0$, are

- $2p-1$ if $-ab$ is a quadratic residue and $f=0$
- $1$ if $-ab$ is a non-QR and $f=0$
- $p+1$ if $-ab$ is a non-QR and $f\neq 0$
- $p-1$ if $-ab$ is a QR and $f\neq 0$.

*Gist of the proof*:

- $f=0$, $-ab$ non-QR only has $X=Y=0$ otherwise $X^2+abY^2=0$ giving $X/Y$ as a square-root of $-ab$.
- $ab$ QR: factors $a(aX^2+bY^2)=(aX-\sqrt{ab} Y)(aX+\sqrt{ab} Y)$ and count.
- $f\neq 0$, $-ab$ non-QR: Either $af$ is a QR, so $abY^2=af-a^2X^2=(\sqrt{af}-aX)(\sqrt{af}+aX)$ and count, or $af$ is a non-QR, in which case a scaling argument says all such $f$ has the same number of solutions and count.

---

Mod 11: we want $x^2+(3y)^2\equiv 1$ and since $-1$ is not a quadratic residue mod 11, there are 12 solutions.

Mod 197: we want $x^2+(3y)^2\equiv -17$ and since $-1$ is a QR mod 197$\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ so there are 196 solutions.

So CRT gives $12\times 196=2352$ solutions mod 2167 and you can choose representatives in $[0,2166]$.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer.-From $3x^2+27y^2+2021=2167n$ we deduce that $n=2+3m$ so we have the equation $$x^2+(3y)^2=771+2167m$$ where $m$ is an integer.

Among $1\le m\le25$, only there are solutions for $m=1,3,7,10,22$ from which it seems there is no pattern to follow.

The found solutions in positive integers are:
$$(x,y)_1=(47,9),(43,11)\\(x,y)_3=(66,18),(54,22)\\(x,y)_7=((8,42),(82,32)\\(x,y)_{10}=(115,32)\\(x,y)_{22}=(22,73),(149,54)$$